# How to ignore a Regex match, if there is a specific prefix

Tags: regex, prefix

I am using this expression to find paths.

```
([^\s\&\=\;\,\<\<\>\"\'\(\)]+\/[\w\/])([^\"\'\n\;\}\)\s]*)
```

Current matches are:

Location: **/user/login.php** xx... **/user/login** xx... **text/html** abcd type **text/html** hey  **abc/def**

I want to ignore match which has "`type` " prefix

So It should be like this.

Location: **/user/login.php** xx... **/user/login** xx... **text/html** abcd type text/html hey  **abc/def**

Comment: Which tool/language are you using? The most obvious solution is to use a **negative look-behind**, but this feature is not supported by all flavours of regex, and occasionally the syntax can even vary.

Comment: c#, yeah as you told, negative look-behind solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those separate matches, you can assert a whitespace boundary to the left or not being precede by `type`

Note that most of the characters that you have in the character class do not need escaping by itself.

```
(?<!\S|\btype )[^\/\s&=;,<>"'()]*(?:\/[^"'\n;})\s]+)+
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S|\btype )` Negative lookbehind, a whitespace boundary to the left or not `type`
- `[^\/\s&=;,<>"'()]*` Optionally match 1 of the listed characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/[^"'\n;})\s]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single occurrence of `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wfnMnh/1)